# Negative binomial Jeffreys prior

Tags: bayesian, prior, negative-binomial-distribution

The negative binomial distribution NB($m,r$) is defined as $$\Pr(X = k) = \left(\frac{r}{r+m}\right)^r \frac{\Gamma(r+k)}{k! \, \Gamma(r)} \left(\frac{m}{r+m}\right)^k \quad\text{for }k = 0, 1, 2, \dots.$$ I'm interested in finding the Jeffreys prior for $m$ and $r$. I could not find this anywhere, most of the results assume $m$ fixed. I tried to derive the expression but got stuck, not sure how to proceed or simplify the expression. 
$$\frac{\partial^2 ln P}{\partial m^2} = \frac{k+r}{(m+r)^2} - \frac{k}{m^2}$$ and 
$$\frac{\partial^2 ln P}{\partial r^2} = ...$$

Comment: There isn't an analytic expression - as you'll end up with digamma and trigamma functions.  You could approximate these with the stirling approximation though.

Comment: In addition, $m$ and $r$ are integers, so you cannot differentiate wrt them.

Comment: @tmrlvi - The linked question appears to assume the shape parameter is known, or so I believe based on the fact that the answer is only one-dimensional and for the probability parameter.  This one seems to be for both parameters.